# Protractor - How to extract a number from [object Object]

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am writing a test to verify the total number of employees in a page, where it is displayed as **Employees (20)**. In my test, it is returned as an [object Object]. How do I extract the number from this?

Comment: Can you upload the code for getEmpCount ?

Comment: this.groupsMenu()
employeeTotal = element(by.xpath(‘//md-card-title-text/div/span’))
return employeeTotal;

Comment: I go to the Employee page and get the element which has the value Employees (20)

Comment: Jane can you update in question in format of script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add getText() in your pages file getEmpCount() function.

```
async getEmpCount() {
    this.groupsMenu.click();
    let title = await this.employeeTotal.getText(); 
    return title;
}
```

Check this example. I have both spec and pages file in the same screenshot.

[image]

Comment: added the script